# NSRect on main screen without window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsrect

I was wondering if it is possible to create an NSRect with maybe an NSMakeRect to make a simple square that will display on the screen without a window or any view behind it, just made all in code.

This is what I have as an example

```
-(void)drawRect
{
   NSRect myNewRect
   myNewRect = NSMakeRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

Thats just a simple starting point but it will not show up on the screen by itself.  what do i need to add?

Thanks

Comment: To display an NSRect you have to draw it somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every drawing operation on Mac OS X requires some window of sort. So no, you cannot draw a rect without a window. But you can create a transparent window without any borders to draw into.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't "*display on the screen without a window or any view behind it*".

You will always be drawing on some layer-backed object (`UIView`, etc).

And `UIView`s must eventually be part of some `UIWindow` hierarchy to display them.

So you can't "*[draw] on main screen without window*" at all. That's not how Core Graphics works.

However, I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
-(void)drawRect
{
   CGRect myNewRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50);

   CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
   CGContextFillRect(ctx, myNewRect);
}
```

Which draws a rectangle in the `UIView` implementing the above `drawRect` method.